# Build failed with an exception, A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError for ionic cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic4

while running an ionic project getting the build failed error,

we create ionic project by this command:

```
ionic start myApp super --type=ionic-angular
```

we run ionic project using fallowing command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

then we get fallowing error

```
 Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/myApp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 13s
/home/myApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/myApp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 BUILD FAILED in 13s

 [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

right now Project Configuration:

node.js 8.10.0, android 8.0, cordova 9.0.0, ionic 4.12.0, gradle 5.2.1

But we have tried this also:

node.js 10, 12  and gradle 5.4.1, 3.3.0 etc

Comment: in your build.gradle file what is line no 20?

Comment: build.gradle line no 20 is:   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: in your config.xml what version you have written?

Comment: xml version='1.0'  and  widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1"

Comment: have u tried removing and then adding android platform ?

Comment: yes I have tried but no luck

Comment: ionic cordova run android --verbose , see what information is provided

Comment: yes we have already tried the suggested command which displays same error.  we also  tried ./gradlew --stop also but  having the same issue